# i want one (left or right side depending on user's choice)of the linearlayout to be replaced with a custom Linear layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am very new in android app development and had a problem in making a app. I am making a app related to cricket. I want one (left or right side depending on user's choice) of the linearlayout to be replaced with a custom Linear layout. This is my code for MainActivity

```
package com.pratham.cricket1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public TextView t1,t2;
    public int ta,tb;
    public int w1,w2;
    public int balls,w,t;
    LinearLayout l1,l2;
    RelativeLayout r1;
    ViewGroup vg1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent i2=getIntent();
        Bundle b2=i2.getExtras();
        if(!b2.isEmpty()){
            balls=b2.getInt("Balls");
            t=b2.getInt("Team won toss");
            w=b2.getInt("Winning team chose");

        }else{}
         t1=findViewById(R.id.TeamA);
         ta=0;
         t2=findViewById(R.id.TeamB);
         ta=0;

         w1=0;
         w2=0;
         l1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.a);
         l2=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.b);
         vg1=(ViewGroup)l2.getParent();
         r1=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.bowling);
         TeamABatting();


    }
    public void a1(View view){
        score_add(1,t1);

    }
    public void a2(View view){
        score_add(2,t1);

    }
    public void a3(View view){
        score_add(3,t1);

    }
    public void a4(View view){
        score_add(4,t1);

    }
    public void a6(View view){
        score_add(6,t1);

    }
    public void b1(View view){
        score_add(1,t2);

    }
    public void b2(View view){
        score_add(2,t2);

    }
    public void b3(View view){
        score_add(3,t2);

    }
    public void b4(View view){
        score_add(4,t2);

    }
    public void b6(View view){
        score_add(6,t2);

    }
    public  void score_add(int a ,TextView t3){
        if(t3==findViewById(R.id.TeamA)){
            ta+=a;
           Score_doner(t3,ta,w1);
        }
        if(t3==findViewById(R.id.TeamB)){
            tb+=a;
            Score_doner(t3,tb,w2);
        }


    }
    public void TeamAOut(View view){
        w1++;
        Score_doner(t1,ta,w1);
    }
    public void TeamBOut(View view){
        w2++;
        Score_doner(t2,tb,w2);
    }
    public void Score_doner(TextView t4,int runs,int wicket){
        t4.setText(Integer.toString(runs)+"/"+Integer.toString(wicket));

    }
    public void TeamABatting(){
        vg1.removeView(l2);
        View v1=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bowling,null);
        vg1.addView(v1);




    }
    public void TeamBBatting(){
        vg1.removeView(l1);
        View v1=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bowling,null);
        vg1.addView(v1);

    }
}
```

This is my main .xml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.pratham.cricket1.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            style="@style/common_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Team A" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            style="@style/common_text"
            android:textSize="96dp"
            android:text="0/0"
            android:id="@+id/TeamA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="a1"
                android:text="+1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="a2"
                android:text="+2" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="a3"
            android:text="+3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="84dp"
            android:onClick="a4"
            android:text="+4" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:onClick="a6"
            android:text="+6" />
        <Button
            android:onClick="TeamAOut"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="OUT!!"
            android:background="#f70303"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:text="Team B"
            style="@style/common_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:textSize="96dp"
            style="@style/common_text"
            android:text="0/0"
            android:id="@+id/TeamB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
             />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="b1"
                android:text="+1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="b2"
                android:text="+2" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="b3"
            android:text="+3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="84dp"
            android:onClick="b4"
            android:text="+4" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:onClick="b6"
            android:text="+6" />

        <Button
            android:onClick="TeamBOut"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#f20404"

            android:text="OUT!!"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want it to be divided in exact half the screen. But I am not achieving the end result.Ignore the excessive coding lines, I will DRY them later. This is the linearlayout I want it to be replaced it with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

        <RelativeLayout

            android:id="@+id/bowling"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"


            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hello"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="Balls Left:"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ballsleft"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/hello" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/overs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@id/ballsleft">

                </ListView>


        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want it to be dynamically added based on user's choice.The layouts should cover only half of the screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M1v5.png)
It is like the image below.
But i want it exactly half.of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the viewGroup that you are taking named as v1 and v2. What I have tried is directing removing the view from l1 and l2 and adding a new view through inflater in the linear layout respectively.
Code below is a glimpse the two methods of TeamA and TeamB.

```
  public void TeamABatting(){
        l2.removeAllViews();
        View v1=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.demo,null);
        l2.addView(v1);




    }
    public void TeamBBatting(){
        l1.removeAllViews();
        View v1=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.demo,null);
        l1.addView(v1);

    }
```

Hope that helps.

Edited Part. here is the full code of the activity.

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public TextView t1,t2;
    public int ta,tb;
    public int w1,w2;
    public int balls = 10,w =1,t =1;
    LinearLayout l1,l2;
    RelativeLayout r1;
    ViewGroup vg1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        t1=findViewById(R.id.TeamA);
        ta=0;
        t2=findViewById(R.id.TeamB);
        ta=0;

        w1=0;
        w2=0;
        l1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.a);
        l2=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.b);
        vg1=(ViewGroup)l2.getParent();
        r1=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.bowling);
        TeamABatting();


    }

    public void a1(View view){
        score_add(1,t1);

    }
    public void a2(View view){
        score_add(2,t1);

    }
    public void a3(View view){
        score_add(3,t1);

    }
    public void a4(View view){
        score_add(4,t1);

    }
    public void a6(View view){
        score_add(6,t1);

    }
    public void b1(View view){
        score_add(1,t2);

    }
    public void b2(View view){
        score_add(2,t2);

    }
    public void b3(View view){
        score_add(3,t2);

    }
    public void b4(View view){
        score_add(4,t2);

    }
    public void b6(View view){
        score_add(6,t2);

    }
    public  void score_add(int a ,TextView t3){
        if(t3==findViewById(R.id.TeamA)){
            ta+=a;
            Score_doner(t3,ta,w1);
        }
        if(t3==findViewById(R.id.TeamB)){
            tb+=a;
            Score_doner(t3,tb,w2);
        }


    }
    public void TeamAOut(View view){
        w1++;
        Score_doner(t1,ta,w1);
    }
    public void TeamBOut(View view){
        w2++;
        Score_doner(t2,tb,w2);
    }
    public void Score_doner(TextView t4,int runs,int wicket){
        t4.setText(Integer.toString(runs)+"/"+Integer.toString(wicket));

    }
    public void TeamABatting(){
        l2.removeAllViews();
        View v1=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.demo,null);
        l2.addView(v1);




    }
    public void TeamBBatting(){
        l1.removeAllViews();
        View v1=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.demo,null);
        l1.addView(v1);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but no effect

Comment: Could you send a screenshot what what you desire and what actually is coming. It would be helpful.

Comment: I am getting This   https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3vx9jtnSxcKN0R6X3kxUll1bEVqaGhtUmRISUNQR3BTcE5F      
                      .I dont have a screen shot of what i need .But i want both the batting and bowling parts equal in width.Hope thats enough

Comment: I am getting this is it correct??? https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-oOlSi4iCx_U/WwQCSycAm1I/AAAAAAAAOxE/eiovxEe0uCwFrHk4RmGqcNpJMY7WZHj9wCK8BGAs/s512/2567362563674520564%253Faccount_id%253D0

Comment: Exactly what i wanted.But the replacement should be dynamically through code

Comment: I am putting the whole code again look in it maybe it can be resolved.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me.I didn't notice earlier that you remove everything inside the linearlayout.Thank You again .Really you made my day